# Change the x axis width dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a problem with xscale. It has to dynamically grow and shrink as per the data.
Right now width is set to 50.

```
w = 50;
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(input.map(function (d) {
                                return d.AppName;
                            })).rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
```

If dataset length is increased from 1 to 6, I like the width variable to have the value w*dataset.length. Right now I'm passing a json object. How xscale can be modified.

Comment: Have you tried using `w*dataset.length` in the call to `rangeRoundBands`?

Comment: The graph wont show up if I add it directly. I was able to resolve the issue by setting it directly in a variable instead of seeting it inside rangeRoundBands arguements

Answer (score 0):

Need to multiply and set the width with length before calling the width in rangeRoundBands.

```
var w = 50 * parseInt(dataset.length)
```